# SQL Server Profiler showing ObjectType 20816 - PQ

Tags: sql, sql-server

A client's database of mine is having some performance issues from time to time. I was running a trace on it using Sql Profiler and I noticed a lot of queries with an **ObjectType** of **20816 - PQ**. I have tried to find some information about this but I have not found a really good explanation. Below is the query that Sql Profiler is returning.

```
select table_id
     , item_guid
     , oplsn_fseqno
     , oplsn_bOffset
     , oplsn_slotid 
from [database].[sys].[filetabl_updates_569821142] with (readpast) 
order by table_id
```

I am not familiar with type of query. Could this be causing some performance issues and what could this query be?

Comment: READPAST hint is kind of cousin of NOLOCK except it only return rows that has not been locked by any other process. Have you tried running this query in SSMS and checked the execution plan ? how big is this table ? is there any table scan clustered index scan in the execution plan???

Comment: A Google query suggests that this has to do with AlwaysOn. See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e95899df-e4fc-4b6a-acd6-534feb0a3b6b/ . I wouldn't assume it's causing performance issues unless you can actually see it doing so; that requires a separate analysis.

Comment: @M.Ali I am not able to run the query. It returns object does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

`ObjectType 20816 - PQ` is a Prepared Query, that may be cached.  There's nothing special about it that might cause a performance problem more than any other query/object type.

The various object types reported by profiler are documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms180953.aspx